# HTML - I cannot copy the value from a read-only input type

Tags: html, input, placeholder, readonly

I have an input set to read-only

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{some variable}" class="form-control" readonly>
```

When I open this in chrome, I cannot copy the text, which is important. I have tried also 'disabled' status, but the same issue.

What is the way to set the code so I can copy the value from the browser?

Big thanks!

Comment: placeholder can not be copied, value can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `value` of that input-field instead of the placeholder:

```html
<input type="text" value="{some variable}" class="form-control" readonly>
```